# HttpContext.Request.RawUrl and localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have AuthorizeAttribute which checks is user logged in, and if not, redirects user to login page.

I want to include returnUrl while redirecting to login page. Currently, I use **filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl** to obtain current url.

The problem is when I host app on IIS, for example `http://localhost/TestApp1` and try to access it, within AuthorizeAttribute, filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl return **/TestApp1** instead of **/**, which is incorrect.

Is there any solution to obtain correct relative path when app is hosted on local IIS?

Comment: Can you provide the full url, and the part you need to include as returnUrl?

Comment: Example url http://localhost/TestApp1/Users and I want only Users as return url

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want like this:

```
string applicationPath = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath;    
string returnUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl.Replace(applicationPath, "");
```